# Cannot decompress .tar.xz file, getting "xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory" from tar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compression, tar, xz

Per [How do I uncompress a tarball that uses .xz?](https://askubuntu.com/a/107976), I tried `tar xf php-5.6.0RC4.tar.xz` and `tar -xJf php-5.6.0RC4.tar.xz` and in both cases I get the following:

```
tar (child): xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

It's [this php-5.6.0RC4.tar.xz](http://downloads.php.net/tyrael/php-5.6.0RC4.tar.xz).

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

The line

```
tar (child): xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
```

gives you the real error. The `xz` programm cannot be executed, probably because it is not installed. To install the `xz` (de)compression tools,  issue one of the following commands depending on your distibution:

```
sudo apt-get install xz-utils          # Debian / Ubuntu
sudo yum install xz                    # RHEL / CentOS
sudo zypper in xz                      # OpenSuSE
sudo pacman -S xz                      # Arch Linux
```

Comment: same solution worked for gzip, error was - tar (child): gzip: Cannot exec: No such file or directory

Comment: For those using RHEL/CentOS, the install command is simply: `yum install xz`.

Comment: @squareskittles Thanks, I added RHEL and two other distros to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was really desperate.